# Disaster Recovery for azure virtual machines using geo-replicated storage

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

We are using Azure Virtual machines to host our application in the cloud. 
Couple of virtual machines are hosting web front-end(state-less) and one virtual machine is hosting SQL Server (data is stored in Data Disk).

As we all know, these virtual machines consist of OS Disk and Data Disk(optional) which uses VHD files stored in blob storage. We are using geo-redundant blob storage which stores these VHD files.

We are now planning for disaster recovery for our cloud application. So if a Microsoft data center is down, is it possible to spin up virtual machines in another data center with the help of OS Disk and Data Disk stored in geo-replicated storage?

Comment: Azure Site Recovery just announced public preview of ‘Disaster Recovery for Azure virtual machines’. Please refer to the blog post below. https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/announcing-disaster-recovery-for-azure-iaas-vms-using-asr Thanks,
Sujay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can not control if/when Microsoft fails over to the secondary (geo-replicated) storage account.  Microsoft controls that.

As I understand it, in the event that Microsoft does declare a disaster and fails over, then your VMs would still work.  Perhaps you'd have to create the VM again from the VHD, but the data would be there (minus anything lost since the last sync to storage).

Comment: Just wondering, how often does a VM sync to storage? Can this be controlled or is it set internally by Microsoft?

Comment: Writes to blob storage (which VMs use for persistent storage) are asynchronously performed behind the scenes. You can't control that.  I don't have any numbers to point too, but I would think it should happen fairly quick (probably a number of factors at play on how fast a write could be replicated to the secondary datacenter).

Comment: @mcollier In case of a total unavailability of a data center, do you know how fast we can switch to a secondary storage?

Comment: @Geethanga with read-only geo-redundant storage, you actually have control on when you attempt to read from the secondary location. The Azure storage team blog at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/12/11/introducing-read-access-geo-replicated-storage-ra-grs-for-windows-azure-storage.aspx provides a good description of what would be needed to read from the secondary.  Unfortunately, this doesn't help the VM story that much. You'd really want write access to secondary, and MSFT still currently controls that.

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to use geo-replicated storage with SQL Server data disks. This is documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn133149.aspx. Specifically, the document states "When creating a storage account, disable geo-replication as consistent write order across multiple disks is not guaranteed. Instead, consider configuring a SQL Server disaster recovery technology between two Azure data centers".